# Trying to get lowest priority number in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, warnings

Hello I am trying to get lowest priority number from all the functions that hook into wp_head.
My code is this.

```
function wpcrown_wpcss_loaded() {   
global $wp_filter;
$lowest_priority = max(array_keys($wp_filter['wp_head']));

add_action('wp_head', 'wpcrown_wpcss_head', $lowest_priority + 1);

$arr = $wp_filter['wp_head'];

}
add_action('wp_head', "wpcrown_wpcss_loaded");
```

But its shown error like this.

```
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array
Warning: max() [<a href='function.max'>function.max</a>]: When only one parameter is given, it must be an array in
```

Please help to solve this.
Thanks

Comment: $lowest_priority = max(array_keys($wp_filter));

Comment: Its just returns "xmlrpc_rsd_apis"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Benoti said `$wp_filter` is no longer an array so `array_keys` is throwing these warnings because expects an array.

If you want to add scripts / styles / whatever you have in `wpcrown_wpcss_head` at the end of the head (to give priority) this should work:

1) Comment this action:

```
// add_action('wp_head', "wpcrown_wpcss_loaded");
```

2) Use this one instead:

```
add_action('wp_head', "wpcrown_wpcss_head");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, Yes this was solution, And i was find this. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull on the use of `$wp_filters` as an array since WordPress 4.7,

Here is the guidelines for wp .4.,7
[Make.wordpress](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/09/08/wp_hook-next-generation-actions-and-filters/) that explain:

If your plugin directly accesses the $wp_filter global rather than using the public hooks API, you might run into compatibility issues.

Case 1: Directly setting callbacks in the $wp_filter array

```
$wp_filter['save_post'][10]['my_special_key'] = array( 'function' => 'my_callback_function', 'accepted_args' => 2 );
```

This will no longer work, and will cause a fatal error. $wp_filter['save_post'] is no longer a simple array. Rather, it is an object that implements the ArrayAccess interface.

You have two options to work around. The first (and preferred) method is to use the add_filter() or add_action() functions.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_callback_function', 10, 2 );
```

If, for some reason, you absolutely cannot, you can still work around this.

```
if ( ! isset( $wp_filter['save_post'] ) ) {
$wp_filter['save_post'] = new WP_Hook();
```

}
    $wp_filter[ 'save_post' ]->callbacks[10]['my_special_key'] = array( 'function' => 'my_callback_function', 'accepted_args' => 2 );

Case 2: Directly unsetting callbacks in the $wp_filter array

```
unset( $wp_filter['save_post'][10][ $my_callback_id ] );
```

This will fail for the same reason as case one. To work around, you can use the standard remove_filter() / remove_action() functions.

```
remove_action( 'save_post', 'my_callback_function', 10, 2 );
```

Or, if you absolutely must access the array directly:

```
if ( isset( $wp_filter[ 'save_post' ] ) ) {
unset( $wp_filter['save_post']->callbacks[10][ $my_callback_id ] );
```

}

Case 3: Checking if a hook is an array

```
if ( isset( $wp_filter['save_post'] ) && is_array( $wp_filter['save_post'] ) ) {
// do something
}
```

This will always return false. $wp_filter['save_post'] is a WP_Hook object. To check if a hook has callbacks, use has_action() or has_filter()

```
if ( has_action( 'save_post' ) ) {
// do something
}
```

Case 4: Moving the $wp_filter array pointer manually
If you’re calling next() or prev() on the $wp_filter array pointer to manually manage the order that callbacks are called in (or if you’re doing it to work around #17817), you will likely be unsuccessful. Use callback priorities, add_action() / add_filter(), and remove_action() / remove_filter() appropriately and let WordPress manage execution order.

Comment: Thanks for share this info. Its related to register hooks. But i am just trying to get lowest priority number.